# Работа с Access из С#

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, access, oledb

Подскажите, существуют ли библиотеки, которые дают возможность работать с Access через безопасный код?

Недавно столкнулся с тем, что jet имеет ограниченные возможности. Т.е к примеру нельзя использовать многие функции, которые мне необходимы(Например Replace).

Может есть какие-то способы работы через безопасный код? Работать через COM не хочется...

Comment: Replace это функция которая реализована внутри office. Работать с ней через не com вряд ли получится. Jet же позволяет выполнять sql запросы. Так что я думаю либо com либо реализуйте внутри своего приложения необходимый функционал сами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Работать через COM не хочется...

Вообще для работы с Access под .NET, как правило, используется ADO.NET, которая интегрирована в саму платформу и полностью поддерживает эту СУБД.
Поэтому, искать дополнительные библиотеки нет смысла. Всё уже есть в самом .NET.

Comment: При попытке выполнить запрос , который содержит Replace, у меня вылетает ошибка, что-то типа "не известная функция Replace." Или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @iluxa1810, Replace это функция из VBA (как уже отметили в более раннем комментарии) в спецификацию SQL, которая используется в Access она не входит. Поэтому воспользоваться ей в SQL запросе не получится.